# How to get a value having same class name in a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, html-tableextract

I have a table like this, from this site [Flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-gold-platinum-32-gb/p/itmehgj9ffpgr5sz?pid=MOBEGFZPCHJHAZVU)

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="specTable">
<tr><th class="groupHead" colspan="2">GENERAL FEATURES</th></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Brand</td><td class="specsValue">SAMSUNG</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Handset Color</td><td class="specsValue">Gold Platinum</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Form</td><td class="specsValue">Bar</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">SIM Size</td><td class="specsValue">Nano SIM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Call Features</td><td class="specsValue">Loudspeaker</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Model Name</td><td class="specsValue">Galaxy S7 Edge</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">Touch Screen</td><td class="specsValue">Yes</td></tr>
<tr><td class="specsKey">SIM Type</td><td class="specsValue">Dual Sim, LTE + LTE</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to get the value **Galaxy S7 Edge** in this row from the table

```
<tr><td class="specsKey">Model Name</td><td class="specsValue">Galaxy S7 Edge</td></tr>
```

I have tried using this code

```
alert(String.valueOf($(".specsValue").eq(5)));
```

But i'm getting output as **Object object**

Comment: `$('.specTable tr:nth-child(7)').find(".specsValue").text()` use this meaning in table at 7th row class specsValue its text

Comment: I have tried your answer, but i'm getting output like this.

function String() { [native code] }

Comment: i updated my comment..what output do you get?

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2787/gEH4NZ.png)

I have used the updated code, but i'm getting next two rows information also.

Comment: you have other element with class `specsValue` in row 7? can you give exact table markup?

Comment: [Table MarkUp](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/2739/tMMhHi.png) - Here is the table markup.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahujm847/) looks good maybe you have other table with class `specTable`?

Comment: Yes, you have said right, i had 4 more tables with same class name "specTable" and in each table rows has same class name "specsValue".

Comment: that is why you are getting other value... if the the table you want to get the `Galaxy S7 Edge` is the first one use `$('.specTable:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(7)').find(".specsValue").text()` just change number in `'.specTable:nth-child(1)` depending on the table if first or secon etc...

Comment: I have update the code what you have giving, but i'm getting an empty alert.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ahujm847/1/)

Comment: I have uploaded the code in jsfiddle please have a look at the structure of the code having starting div and ending div tag. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/krthk08/L6hdxygf/). Thank you Mr.guradio

Comment: use `2` try this `$('.specTable:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(7)').find(".specsValue").text()` check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L6hdxygf/1/)

Comment: Works like a charm sir. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: np mate glad to help :) happy coding